# Pass NSMutableArray from AppDelegate

Tags: nsmutablearray

This I could handle:

```
myArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[myArray addObject:@"some1"];
[myArray addObject:@"some2"];
```

I manage to transfer a basic NSMutableArray from AppDelegate.m to 'anotherClass'.m, Im using it in a tableView, but now I need to go one step further =)

What if my array looks like this

```
mySecoundArray =[NSMutableArray arrayWithObects: sak1,sak2,nil];
```

Where

```
BombDoc *sak1 = [[BombDoc alloc] initWithTitle@"Title1" weight:10 otherField:@"Special" ];
```

As I mentions above I would like to use the mySecoundArray in my tableView, the problem is that I do not know how to pick out sak1:s first info, the Title, so I can use it as the name of the TableCell.

I would be glad if anyone out there can give me a hint, better of, an explicit line of code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, your problem is that you don't know how to **access** the data members(properties) of the item in the array?

You can get the object in the array by **casting** it to the right type:

```
BombDoc *sak1 = (BombDoc*)[mySecoundArray objectAtIndex:0];
// Now we can access sak1's information
NSString *title = [sak1 title];
NSInteger weight = [sak1 weight];
// Etc.
```

Hope this answers your question.

Best regards, Rat

**EDIT:**

You might also suffer from an empty array after you've passed the `mySecoundArray` to the table view.

As you see, you are using **2** different ways for initializing your `NSMutableArray`:

```
// Returns an instance of NSMutableArray
myArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
// Returns an auto-released instance of NSMutableArray
mySecoundArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:sak1,sak2,nil];
```

You might want to get a non-auto-released instance instead:

```
mySecoundArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:sak1,sak2,nil];
```

You must remember that using this approach requires you to release `mySecoundArray` manually.

Comment: Thanks Rat, I'll give it a try, you seamed to understand my Q i hope I can figure out your A, Gonna give it some hours!